# Управление принтеров в linux без cups

Tags: python, linux, usb, raspberry-pi, label-printer

Есть принтер меток(label printer) и машина на linux(raspberry).

Обычно я использовал для печати `cups` и высылал необработанные файлы `.prn`, но проблема в том, что `cups` слишком долго думает, перед тем как отправить что-то на печать.

Принтер `wincode lp433` по сути аналог `zebra epl2`, поэтому драйвера в `cups` выбрал именно для zebra.

Появилась идея: так как принтер подключен по usb, то можно напрямую по usb высылать в память RAM эти файлы. Скачал программу `USB Monitoring Studio` и посмотрел, что на принтер высылаются те же файлы `.prn` напрямую на принтер из win7 и работает все очень быстро.

Теперь вопрос: как с помощью скрипта в `python` выслать все это дело на принтер, может есть какие библиотеки?

Ниже привожу пример того, что нужно выслать в оперативную память принтера. То, что справа мне известно - это содержимое `.prn` файла, а вот что слева непонятно и как это выслать?

[image: то, что справа мне известно, это содержимое .prn файла, а вот что слева непонятно и как это выслать?]

Comment: В общем удалось узнать, что слева это hex code

Comment: я в пайтон не умею, но реализовывал подобную задачу на node.js, пишу как знаю: нужна лишь библиотека умеющая работать с usb (возможно в винду понадобится поставить usb-драйвер, например Zadig) - читаешь список устройств `usb.getDeviceList()`, по `device.deviceDescriptor.idVendor` выбираешь своё устройство, открываешь, claim и можно в него что-то посылать (если ты знаешь в каком формате принтер принимает данные)

Comment: @norbornen ,спасибо за ответ,  в общем примерно так и представлял, мне нужно hex тот, что слева выслать на принтер по usb.

Comment: было бы здорово если бы ты конкретно описал в чём ты видишь проблему(проблемы). гораздо проще давать ответы на конкретные вопросы

Comment: @norbornen ,посмотри пожалуйста в ответе ниже, если не сложно, там я описал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любое устройство в линуксе имеет свой файловый дескриптор и работать с ним можно как с обычным файлом. Посмотрите у себя на малине содержимое `/dev/usb`, там должен быть файл lp(0,1,...), вот это и есть дескриптор принтера. 
Основная фишка в том что ваш prn файл можно в него просто вывести например `cat blabla.prn > /dev/usb/lp0` либо открыть его на запись из питона (как обычный файл) и просто попробовать записать данные.

Но а вообще все принтеры этикеток имеют свой собственный язык команд. Например Zebra - EPL1/2, DataMax - DPL, Custom - SVELTA. Многие из них также поддерживают PCL и/или POS. 
Все производители в основном рекомендуют использовать их набор команд. Как плюс это дает дополнительные плюшки такие как загрузка изображений в память принтера или загрузка шрифтов для печати или чтение содержимого RFID карты (если принтер оборудован считывателем), более быстрая печать, сохранение шаблонов для печати в принтере (потом передаются только значения полей) и т.д.

Comment: Ну, в малине не нашел каталога /dev/usb, а есть /dev/bus/usb и в этом каталоге есть папка 001 и в ней файл 001. попробовал сделать: cat home/dietpi/tmpFile.prn > /dev/bus/usb/001/001, но выдает ошибку cat: write error: Invalid argument

Comment: Как раз таки с помощью языка принтера я генерирую .prn файлы в python и сохраняю их как tmpFile.prn

Comment: а можете посмотреть есть ли в /dev/ttyUSB(0,1,2...)

Comment: @ИльяКузьмич если проблема в том что ты не знаешь точку монтирования устройства то в [этом ответе](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144735/296262) есть очень достойный скрипт, который покажет список устройств. а вообще `lsusb -v` для развлечения

Comment: @0xDEADBEEF ttyUSB файла нет, есть tty(0,1,2...) но они все 0kb

Comment: @norbornen ,вот что удалось узнать)                                                                               
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/dev
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-1/dev
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/usbmisc/lp0/dev

Comment: Все верно ты до этого расписал,спасибо большое) Удалось сгенерировать /dev/usb/lp0 в итоге печатается cat /home/dietpi/tmpFile.prn > /dev/usb/lp0